# Multiplication doesn't give the right answer

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, long-integer, multiplication

I'm working with multiplications in my objective c application. The problem is, when i do some multiplications, sometimes it gives me a false result :

Exemple :

```
int intern = 77986;
int secondNumber = 70654;
long long int multiply = intern * secondNumber;
NSLog(@"Intern : %i   two : %i   mult : %lli", intern, secondNumber, multiply);
```

The result is :

Intern : 77986   two : 70654   mult : 1215055548

The result would be 5510022844

I don't understand... Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple overflow issue. An operation with two `int` variables is done as an `int`. But the result is too big for `int` so it overflows. Then the overflowed result is assigned to the `long long int`.

Making either (or both) of the first two `int` variables into `long long int` will result in the operation being done as a `long long int` resulting in the expected and correct result.

To clarify, you can either do:

```
long long int intern = 77986;
// and the rest
```

or do:

```
long long int multiply = (long long int)intern * secondNumber;
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert an int into long long int please ?

Comment: Of course. I wouldn't have suggested it if it couldn't be done. Either change its type or use a cast.

Comment: juste as long long int tamp = (long long int) intern for example ?

Comment: With that you don't even need the cast. The compiler will do the cast automatically.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `long long int` is equivalent to `long long` (and indeed `long int` to `long`) in case they encounter the `ll` suffix

Comment: @RyanDignard That's true. Once you add modifiers to `int`, the `int` becomes optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
 125055548 -> 0x 486C46BC
5510022844 -> 0x1486C46BC
```

Since you're multiplying ints, the result is an int, and gets truncated down to 32bits.

Comment: Without some explanation and context the answer is close to meaningless.